# How to recreate exceptions of recurring appointment in the proper order?

Tags: delphi, soap, exchangewebservices

I have the following issue:

- Assume a recurring event on 15, 19, 23, 27... February
- In Exchange the '19' occurrence was moved to 21
- Next, the '15' occurrence was moved to 20. So it moves *past the original start date* (19) of the 2nd occurrence

Now if I want to recreate this recurring event in Exchange I first create the master event, i.e. automatically with all its regular occurrences, and then I must modify some of these to create the exceptions **in this same order**. If I don't do that and first create the '15->20' occurrence, this will fail, because its modified date is past the regular '19' occurrence.
 Exchange will give me the *Modified occurrence is crossing or overlapping adjacent occurrence* error.

But how do I determine the order? In a simple test case the GetItem call for the master event does *not* give me the `ModifiedOccurrences` in the order in which they were created:

```
 <t:ModifiedOccurrences>
    <t:Occurrence>
       <t:ItemId Id="AAMkA[snip]pQAAEA==" ChangeKey="DwA[snip]bix"/>
       <t:Start>2016-02-20T09:00:00Z</t:Start>
       <t:End>2016-02-20T10:30:00Z</t:End>
       <t:OriginalStart>2016-02-15T09:00:00Z</t:OriginalStart>
    </t:Occurrence>
    <t:Occurrence>
       <t:ItemId Id="AAMkA[snip]pQAAEA==" ChangeKey="DwA[snip]bix"/>
       <t:Start>2016-02-21T09:00:00Z</t:Start>
       <t:End>2016-02-21T10:30:00Z</t:End>
       <t:OriginalStart>2016-02-19T09:00:00Z</t:OriginalStart>
    </t:Occurrence>
 </t:ModifiedOccurrences>
```

If I do a GetItem for those two exceptions I see no appointment property that I can use to determine the order in which they were created:

- `LastModifiedTime` does not say anything, the exceptions may have been modified repeatedly.
- `OriginalStart` or `RecurrenceId` (a date equal to `OriginalStart`) don't work, because this process goes in both directions (the exceptions can also be *back* in time).
- I see no other properties in the [CalenderItem documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564765%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) that seem usable.

I tried to create the master *with* its exceptions in one step, by inserting the same `ModifiedOccurrences` block in the `CreateItem` call but this gives a schema validation error because I have to supply ItemIDs (but Exchange creates those.)

So how can I determine in which order I must recreate these exceptions (or did I overlook something and *is* it possible to create the master event with its exceptions in one step)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. The crucial remark in my question was:

> OriginalStart or RecurrenceId (a date equal to OriginalStart) don't work, because this process goes in both directions (the exceptions can also be back in time).

If you *split* forward and backward occurrence moves and handle them in two blocks, it works. Actually, three blocks:

1. Remove deleted occurrences
2. Create occurrences moved forward (Start > OriginalStart) from last date to first date
3. Create occurrences moved backward (Start < OriginalStart) from first date to last date

Essential parts of the (Delphi XE2) code using Developer Express components:

```
type 
   TIDDate = class
                FOrgStart,
                FStart   : TDateTime;
                FIndex   : Integer;
                Constructor Create(AOrgStart,AStart: TDateTime; AIndex: Integer);
             end;

constructor TIDDate.Create(AOrgStart,AStart: TDateTime; AIndex: Integer);
begin
   FOrgStart := AOrgStart;
   FStart    := AStart;
   FIndex    := AIndex;
end;

function TDataModuleSyncExchange.InsertExchangeMasterEvent(AMasterEvent: TcxSchedulerEvent; var AMasterItemID, AMasterEntryID: String): Boolean;
var
   lExchOccurrence: TcxSchedulerEvent;
   i              : Integer;
   lDateList      : TObjectList;
   lIDDate        : TIDDate;
   lEventList     : TcxSchedulerEventList;

begin { Main InsertExchangeMasterEvent }
   [snip]
   lEventList := AMasterEvent.GetRecurrenceChain;  // DevEx code

   // 1. Deleted occurrences 
   for i := 0 to lEventList.Count-1 do
   begin
      lExchOccurrence := lEventList.Items[i];
      if lExchOccurrence.EventType = etException then
         DeleteExchangeItem(lOccurItemID);  // Own code elsewhere
   end;

   // 2. Occurrences moved forward (Start > OriginalStart) from last date to first date
   lDateList := TObjectList.Create(true);
   for i := 0 to lEventList.Count-1 do
   begin
      lExchOccurrence := lEventList.Items[i];
      if lExchOccurrence.EventType = etCustom then
      begin
         lIDDate := TIDDate.Create(lExchOccurrence.GetOriginalDate,lExchOccurrence.Start,i);
         lDateList.Add(lIDDate);
      end;
   end;
   lDateList.SortList(function (Item1, Item2: Pointer): Integer
                      var lDT1,lDT2: TDateTime;
                      begin
                         lDT1 := TIDDate(Item1).FOrgStart;
                         lDT2 := TIDDate(Item2).FOrgStart;
                         if lDT1 > lDT2 then
                            Result := 1
                         else
                            if lDT1 < lDT2 then
                               Result := -1
                            else
                              Result := 0;
                      end);

   for i := lDateList.Count-1 downto 0 do
      with TIDDate(lDateList[i]) do
         if FStart > FOrgStart then
            CreateOccurrence(FIndex,lOccurChangeKey);   // Own code elsewhere

   // 3. Occurrences moved backward (Start < OriginalStart) from first date to last date
   for i := 0 to lDateList.Count-1 do
      with TIDDate(lDateList[i]) do
         if FStart < FOrgStart then
            CreateOccurrence(FIndex,lOccurChangeKey);   // Own code elsewhere

   lDateList.Free;
```